# Access custom attributes of .NET class inside custom json converter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

In my project, I have written a custom json converter to trim the white-spaces present in the string property.

Here is an example of the typical class we will use,

```
public class Candidate
{
    public string CandidateName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my custom json converter

```
public class StringSanitizingConverter : JsonConverter
{       
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue , JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                string sanitizedString = (reader.Value as string).Trim();

                if (StringSanitizeOptions.HasFlag(StringSanitizeOptions.ToLowerCase))
                    sanitizedString = sanitizedString.ToLowerInvariant();

                return sanitizedString;
            }

        return reader.Value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var text = (string)value;
        if (text == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else
            writer.WriteValue(text.Trim());
    }
}
```

With my custom converter I am now able to format the string by trimming any white-spaces present sent to the action methods using my 'Candidate' as one of its parameter.

```
public void Post(ComplexType complexTypeParameter){
}
```

Everything worked well so far. I later wanted to enhance this json converter to format the string properties based on the attributes set to the string property in the Candidate class. for example, assume I have written my candidate class like this,

```
 public class Candidate
 {
     [StringSanitizingOptions(Option.ToLowerCase)]
     public string CandidateName { get; set; }
 }
```

And if I wanted to format the string properties of a class based on the custom attribute configuration inside the json converter , I am not able to access this custom attribute and its configuration inside the ReadJson method of the custom converter.

Here is what I have tried so far but with no luck,

1. Not present in the `CustomAttributes` property of the `objectType`
   parameter sent to the `ReadJson()` method.
2. Was trying to see if I could extract the parent class of the property inside the `ReadJson()` method, so that I could apply reflection on the class to extract the custom attributes given to any of its property,but I could not extract that too.

Comment: *I wanted to format the string properties of a class based on the custom attribute configuration inside the json converter* -- I don't understand what you mean by this.  Can you clarify with a [mcve]?  In general Json.NET is a contract-based serializer; each type has its own contract which is generally not by parent(s).  But maybe you want something like [NewtonSoft JsonConverter - Access other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47866386/3744182) or [Passing additional information to a JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31927365/3744182)?

Comment: As you can see from the above code that I use the custom converter to trim the white-spaces present in the Candidate.CandidateName, this is the default require behavior. 

What I want is basically to convert the Candidate.CandidateName value to lower case if the attribute [StringSanitizingOptions(Option.ToLowerCase)] is present for the property.

The challenge here for me is I am not sure how to access the custom attribute give to the CandidateName property inside the ReadJson method of the custom JsonConverter class.

Comment: @dbc I had a look at the fiddle code of yours in the link https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mmNPj . Obviously you seem to have written this code for customizing the serialization process. In case if I want to customize the deserialization process based on the custom attributes present in the property. could you please shed some thoughts on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack of containing object(s) is not made available to [`JsonConverter.ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm), thus you cannot do what you want inside `ReadJson()`.

Instead, what you can do is to create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that applies an appropriately configured instance of `StringSanitizingConverter` based on the properties of the object for which a contract is being generated.

First, let's say your data model, attribute, and `JsonConverter` look like the following (where I had to modify a few things to make your code compile and include some additional test cases):

```
public class Candidate
{
    [StringSanitizingOptions(Option.ToLowerCase)]
    public string CandidateName { get; set; }

    [StringSanitizingOptions(Option.DoNotTrim)]
    public string StringLiteral { get; set; }

    public string DefaultString { get; set; }

    public List<string> DefaultStrings { get; set; }
}

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property | System.AttributeTargets.Field | System.AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class StringSanitizingOptionsAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public Option StringSanitizeOptions { get; set; }

    public StringSanitizingOptionsAttribute(Option stringSanitizeOptions)
    {
        this.StringSanitizeOptions = stringSanitizeOptions;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Option
{
    Default = 0,
    ToLowerCase = (1<<0),
    DoNotTrim = (1<<1),
}

public static class StringSanitizeOptionsExtensions
{
    public static bool HasFlag(this Option options, Option flag)
    {
        return (options & flag) == flag;
    }
}

public class StringSanitizingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly Option options;

    public StringSanitizingConverter() : this(Option.Default) { }

    public StringSanitizingConverter(Option options)
    {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                var sanitizedString = (reader.Value as string);

                if (!options.HasFlag(Option.DoNotTrim))
                    sanitizedString = sanitizedString.Trim();

                if (options.HasFlag(Option.ToLowerCase))
                    sanitizedString = sanitizedString.ToLowerInvariant();

                return sanitizedString;
            }

        return reader.Value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // WriteJson is never called with null
        var text = (string)value;

        if (!options.HasFlag(Option.DoNotTrim))
            text = text.Trim();

        writer.WriteValue(text);
    }
}
```

Next, grab `ConfigurableContractResolver` from [How to add metadata to describe which properties are dates in JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083201/3744182), and define the extension method `JsonContractExtensions.AddStringConverters()`:

```
public static class JsonContractExtensions
{
    public static JsonContract AddStringConverters(this JsonContract contract)
    {
        if (contract is JsonPrimitiveContract)
        {
            if (contract.UnderlyingType == typeof(string))
                contract.Converter = new StringSanitizingConverter();
        }
        else if (contract is JsonObjectContract)
        {
            var objectContract = (JsonObjectContract)contract;
            foreach (var property in objectContract.Properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    var attr = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(StringSanitizingOptionsAttribute), true)
                        .Cast<StringSanitizingOptionsAttribute>()
                        .SingleOrDefault();
                    if (attr != null)
                    {
                        property.Converter = property.MemberConverter = new StringSanitizingConverter(attr.StringSanitizeOptions);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return contract;
    }
}

public class ConfigurableContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // This contract resolver taken from the answer to
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047308/how-to-add-metadata-to-describe-which-properties-are-dates-in-json-net
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083201/3744182

    readonly object contractCreatedPadlock = new object();
    event EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> contractCreated;
    int contractCount = 0;

    void OnContractCreated(JsonContract contract, Type objectType)
    {
        EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> created;
        lock (contractCreatedPadlock)
        {
            contractCount++;
            created = contractCreated;
        }
        if (created != null)
        {
            created(this, new ContractCreatedEventArgs(contract, objectType));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> ContractCreated
    {
        add
        {
            lock (contractCreatedPadlock)
            {
                if (contractCount > 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("ContractCreated events cannot be added after the first contract is generated.");
                }
                contractCreated += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (contractCreatedPadlock)
            {
                if (contractCount > 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("ContractCreated events cannot be removed after the first contract is generated.");
                }
                contractCreated -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        OnContractCreated(contract, objectType);
        return contract;
    }
}

public class ContractCreatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public JsonContract Contract { get; private set; }
    public Type ObjectType { get; private set; }

    public ContractCreatedEventArgs(JsonContract contract, Type objectType)
    {
        this.Contract = contract;
        this.ObjectType = objectType;
    }
}

public static class ConfigurableContractResolverExtensions
{
    public static ConfigurableContractResolver Configure(this ConfigurableContractResolver resolver, EventHandler<ContractCreatedEventArgs> handler)
    {
        if (resolver == null || handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        resolver.ContractCreated += handler;
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Then, finally you can deserialize and serialize `Candidate` as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ConfigurableContractResolver
    {
    }.Configure((s, e) => { e.Contract.AddStringConverters(); }),
};

var candidate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Candidate>(json, settings);

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(candidate, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

1. I don't know why the stack of containing object(s) is not available in `ReadJson()`.  Possibilities include:

   - Simplicity.
   - A [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object is "an unordered set of name/value pairs", so trying to access the containing .Net object while reading a property value isn't guaranteed to work, since the information required might not have been read in yet (and the parent might not even have been constructed).
2. Because a default instance of `StringSanitizingConverter` is applied to the contract generated for `string` itself, it is not necessary to add the converter to [`JsonSerializer.SettingsConverters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm).  This in turn may lead to a small performance enhancement as [`CanConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) will no longer get called.
3. [`JsonProperty.MemberConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_MemberConverter.htm) was recently marked obsolete in [Json.NET 11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1) but must be set to the same value as `JsonProperty.Converter` in previous versions of Json.NET.  If you are using 11.0.1 or a more recent version you should be able to remove the setting.
4. You may want to [cache the contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182) for best performance.
5. To modify `JsonSerializerSettings` in [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api), see *[JsonSerializerSettings and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35772387/3744182)*, *[Web API: Configure JSON serializer settings on action or controller level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44499041/3744182)*, *[How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625/3744182)* or *[ASP.NET Core API JSON serializersettings per request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828302/3744182)*, depending on your requirements and the version of the framework in use.

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jy0Ogd).

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answer. I was able to apply this solution to solve my problem. Very helpful.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for on Friday 

"Instead, what you can do is to create a custom contract resolver that applies an appropriately configured instance of StringSanitizingConverter based on the properties of the object for which a contract is being generated."

I learned this from your code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mmNPj and was able to achieve my goal. :-)