# Custom Attribute reflection on property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, json.net

I have this basic class with one custom `Attribute`

```
public class Foo
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public DateTime CurrentDate {get;set;}
}
```

I'm using reflection to see if `CurrentDate` has a `MyAttribute` on it.

I create a new instance of `Foo`:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

I reflect on `foo`:

```
foo.GetType().GetProperty("CurrentDate").GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

this gives me my custom attributes.

However, if I reflect like this:

```
foo.CurrentDate.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

it returns what seems to be native attributes and mine is not in there.

So my question is, why is it doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.CurrentDate.GetType()` will return `typeof(DateTime)`. That's because `foo.CurrentDate` is declared as a `DateTime`. `GetType()` returns information about the type of the value you give it, not information about the property that the value came from.

Do you mean to do something like `foo.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(foo.CurrentDate)).GetCustomAttributes()`?

Comment: The use case is I have a custom JsonConverter that returns `true` in `CanConvert(Type objectType)` if `objectType == typeOf(DateTime)` and that `objectType` has a custom `Attribute`

Comment: @JohanP: JsonConverters fulfill a different use case from the one you mention. You can do what you're talking about using a custom Contract Resolver that watches for custom attributes on properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088492/120955 for a description of the difference between the two.

Comment: @JohanP - *The use case is I have a custom JsonConverter* -- in that case this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Since this answers the question you asked, I'd go ahead and ask a new question that describes your real problem.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior It seems I need a contract resolver for attributes then. I have the JsonConverter because I do need custom deserialization for DateTime so I thought I could get away with just having the converter.

Comment: @JohanP - sounds like you might want something like this then: [Access custom attributes of .NET class inside custom json converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49991050/3744182).