# How change object type to another when deserialising with JSON.Net or call default serialiser?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

When serialise, I write ClassName to object into _CurrentClassName property. And when read json with JSON.Net library I need to change object to value from this property.

```
{
 "Field1": 0,
 "Field2": "34",
 "_CurrentClassName": "MyCustomClass"
}


class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
...
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsClass;
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = existingValue;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            JToken jToken;
            if (jObject.TryGetValue("_CurrentClassName", out jToken))
            {
                var t = jToken.Value<string>();
                Type tt = Type.GetType(objectType.Namespace + "." + t);
                value = Activator.CreateInstance(tt);
                return value;
            }
        }
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);            
    }

...
}
```

Comment: You could do something similar to what is done in the answer to [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528648/json-net-serialization-of-type-with-polymorphic-child-object/29531372#29531372).

Comment: Thanks. Similar, but I can't use "hard" type, my CanConvert looks like:
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType.IsClass;
            }

Comment: Are you married to that property name and syntax or could you just use Json.Net built in handling of this?

Comment: If you pass in a `new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }` to the serialization or deserialization methods you will add a property like `$"type": "Namespace.Type, Assembly"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the object type has been inferred and the object has been instantiated, you can use [`JsonSerializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader())`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm) to populate it.

For instance:

```
public abstract class CustomJsonConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract Type InferType(JToken token, Type objectType, object existingValue);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var actualType = InferType(token, objectType, existingValue);
        if (existingValue == null || existingValue.GetType() != actualType)
        {
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(actualType);
            existingValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
        }
        using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
        {
            // Using "populate" avoids infinite recursion.
            serializer.Populate(subReader, existingValue);
        }
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CustomJsonConverter : CustomJsonConverterBase
{
    public const string ClassPropertyName = @"_CurrentClassName";

    protected override Type InferType(JToken token, Type objectType, object existingValue)
    {
        if (token is JObject)
        {
            var typeName = (string)token[ClassPropertyName];
            if (typeName != null)
            {
                var actualType = Type.GetType(objectType.Namespace + "." + typeName);
                if (actualType != null)
                    return actualType;
            }
        }
        return objectType;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[`CustomCreationConverter<T>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/CustomCreationConverter.cs) also uses `serializer.Populate()` to fill in the just-allocated object so this is a standard way to solve this problem.

Note that you are partially replicating Json.NET's built-in [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I will try understand and use this.

Comment: Working with filter system types. Thank you!
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            return objectType.IsClass 
                && objectType.Namespace != null 
                && !objectType.Namespace.StartsWith("System") ;
        }

Answer (score 1):

If you're not married to the `_CurrentClassName` property name or its value syntax you could use Json.Net's built in handling of types.

When serializing or deserializing you can pass in a `JsonSerializerSettings` object controlling the serialization or deserialization.

On this object you can set a `TypeNameHandling` property that controls how Json.Net serializes and deserializes the exact type being processed.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example:

```
void Main()
{
    var t = new Test { Key = 42, Value = "Meaning of life" };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        t, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
    Console.WriteLine(json);

    var obj  =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().FullName);
}

public class Test
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "$type": "UserQuery+Test, LINQPadQuery",
  "Key": 42,
  "Value": "Meaning of life"
}
UserQuery+Test
```

Here you can see that the type of the object being returned from deserialization is the `Test` class.

Comment: Married. Using C# namespaces in typename in not acceptable