# How can you patch an existing object with custom serialization using Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, polymorphism

Json.Net has support for controlling custom serialization using derived versions of `JsonConverter`. These enable a developer to control how serialization for a particular type occurs. There are a few ways a JsonConverter can be associated with a type or field including such as using a `[JsonConverter]` attribute on the member or type.

However these are only called if using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` or `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` for deserializing to new instances of objects or serializing existing objects. If you need to patch or update an existing object, `JsonConverter.Populate` is what is referred to to use, but does not use converters. Instead, it relies solely on reflection and naive object creation which blows up if you implement polymorphic serialization and/or use abstract classes or interfaces.

```cs
if(_value == null)
{
    _value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonContent, WebConstants.JSON_SERIALIZER_SETTINGS);
}
else
{
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonContent, _value, WebConstants.JSON_SERIALIZER_SETTINGS);
}
```

My question is; what can you do in this case to control custom serialization when patching existing objects in Json.Net? Ideally I would like to reuse the logic from the custom `JsonConverter` implementations so that I am not implementing this logic twice.

Comment: [`JsonConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader, Type, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) has the `existingValue` argument so you can just call the converter directly and pass in `_value`.  Of course the converter must be written correctly to populate the `existingValue` rather than ignore it -- and many aren't.

Comment: Examples of converters using the `existingValue` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39267164/3744182) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35590069/3744182) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638748/3744182).

Comment: Does that answer your question?  If not, what additional help do you need?