# How to deserialize JSON with Json.Net and Xamarin with SubTypes?

Tags: c#, json.net, subtype

I'm trying to deserialize this json:

```
{
  "teaser": [{
              "id": "...",
              "type": "category",
              "url": "https:...",
            },{
              "id": "...",
              "type": "brand",
              "url": "https:...",
              "videoCount": 1,
            },{
              "id": "...",
              "type": "video",
              "url": "https:...",
              "headline": "...",
            }]
}
```

It has a list of teasers whereby each teaser is different depending on its type. 
These would be my objects:

```
public class StartPage
{
        public IList<Teaser> Teaser { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Teaser
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Video : Teaser
{
        public string Headline { get; set; }
}

public class Brand : Teaser
{
        public int VideoCount { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to Json.NET and Xamarin and couldn't find a solution for this case yet. Before, when I was using Android Studio and Gson, I could register sybtypes the following way:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Teaser> teaserRuntimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(
                Teaser.class, "type")
                .registerSubtype(Video.class, Teaser.TYPE_VIDEO)
                .registerSubtype(Brand.class, Teaser.TYPE_BRAND)
                .registerSubtype(Category.class, Teaser.TYPE_CATEGORY);

        return new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(teaserRuntimeTypeAdapterFactory);
```

Is there a similar way to achieve what I want with Json.NET I have overlooked yet?

Comment: have you read the documentation of json.net https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm or samples https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm ?

Comment: Read this stackoverflow thread about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528648/json-net-serialization-of-type-with-polymorphic-child-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create custom `JsonConverter`  please below snippet and find [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ZRqt5) dot net fiddle

```
string json ="{ 'Teaser': [{ 'id': '...', 'type': 'category', 'url': 'https:...', },{ 'id': '...', 'type': 'brand', 'url': 'https:...', 'videoCount': 1, },{ 'id': '...', 'type': 'video', 'url': 'https:...', 'headline': '...', }]}";

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StartPage>(json);

public class BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
        {
            if (typeof(Teaser).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && !objectType.IsAbstract)
                return null; // pretend TableSortRuleConvert is not specified (thus avoiding a stack overflow)
            return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
        }
    }

public class BaseConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        static JsonSerializerSettings SpecifiedSubclassConversion = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter() };

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(Teaser));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            switch (jo["type"].Value<string>())
            {
                case "video":
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Video>(jo.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion);
                case "brand":
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Brand>(jo.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion);
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // won't be called because CanWrite returns false
        }
    }
```

Feel free to create custom logic in `switch case` hard code class name might not good idea instead create `enum` or something like but this is how you can achieve this type of scenario

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for! Had to use System.Reflection and rewrite the ResolveContractConverter a bit to `typeof(Teaser).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType.GetTypeInfo()) && !objectType.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract` but everything else worked like a charm!