# How to create a generic json deserialization factory

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, deserialization

I have a scenario where I receive json as a string.  Each piece of json is formatted the same, except for a collection of items within.  Take this as simplified examples:

```
{ 
    "Type": "A",
    "Items": [
       { "Name": "Item 1" },
       { "Name": "Item 2" }
    ]
}
```

```
{ 
    "Type": "B",
    "Items": [
       { "Counter": 1 },
       { "Counter": 2 }
    ]
}
```

I have the following models in code to represent this:

```cs
public enum Type
{
    A, B
}
public class InstanceTypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class InstanceTypeB
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

*note: in the future, the types will be extended further, say to D, E, and F for this example.  All of which will have an item collection structured differently again.*

And I would like to deserialize this into a model, for example:

```cs
public class Container<T>
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

*where T would be either instanceTypeA or instanceTypeB*

As mentioned, I receive the json shown at the top as a string.  And it's the "type" enum that dictates the type of the object held in the items collection.  I'm struggling to find a very generic way to implement this serialization.

I was thinking the factory pattern could help but not sure how to implement this - has anyone tackled a similar problem.

In my code, I happen to know if it's type A, B etc before actually attempting serialization.  I could do this:

```cs
switch(obj.Type) 
{
   case A: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<A>>(obj.Json)
   case B: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<B>>(obj.Json)
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that the calling code needs to then know its dealing with `Container<A>` or `Container<B>` etc.  Which isn't generic at all.  I can't get A or B to implement a common interface as they are both completely different.  Bit stumped with this - I was hoping Factory pattern could help but can't see how - has anyone dealt with a similar issue before?

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: You might introduce a non-generic abstract base class, in which case the technique from [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182) could work.

Comment: The switch is essentially your factory method's content, isn't it?

Comment: @rob-mccabe Did you get this figured out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the `Type` property to dictate what type is used.  When using the Newtonsoft Json serializer, you can include the type of an object in the JSON document.  That way, when the serializer deserializes the string, it will understand what types to use.  So you could completely drop the `Type` property and just check the type of object in the array.  I believe you need to set the `TypeNameHandling` property of the settings object passed into the serializer.  Once you see the serializer outputting a `$type` property with your objects in the JSON string, you know that you've done it right.