# Customize deserializer to store different objects in a property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

An API server endpoint can return one of the followings:

```
{
    "type": "apple",
    "color": "red"
}
```

which can be deserialized into the class `Apple`

or

```
{
    "type": "orange",
    "size": "big"
}
```

which can be deserialized into the class `Orange`.

I've created a class `Fruit` with just one property `fruitInstance` (which is an `object`) and it will store an instance of either `Apple` or `Orange`.

Is there a way I can customize the JSON.NET deserializer of `Fruit` to do the following?

- Go through possible fruit types one by one (only `Apple`, `Orange` in this case but we can support more later)
- Try to deserialize the response (JSON string) into `Apple` for example
- If the deserialization throws exception, try next one (e.g. `Orange`) until the deserialization is successful
- On success, store the deserialized instance (e.g. Orange) in the `frusitInstance` property

UPDATE: Fruit is not a parent class of Apple/Orange and we cannot make it so due to requirement. In other words, we cannot use `JsonSubTypes`. Let's imagine later the payload can be an integer (e.g. 15) and Fruit will be able to deserialize the payload (integer) into an Integer and store it in `fruitInstance`.

Comment: You can create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to deserialize your class hierarchy.  Please see [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182), [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) or [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) for details.

Comment: Do those three questions answer yours also, or do you need more help?  If so, can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve], especially the `Fruit` class as well as `Apple` and `Orange`?  Also, why are you using composition instead of inheritance for `Fruit`?

Comment: `JsonSubtypes` is possible to use here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out JsonSubTypes but unfortunately Fruit is not a parent class of Apple/Orange and we cannot make it so due to requirement

Answer (score 0):

There might be a good reason you want to write a custom JsonConverter but the problem you described here can be tackled through another approach too if you have some control over JSON being received.
You can consider `Fruit` as your base and `Apple`, `Orange` (and so on) as its derived types. Then you can **Deserialize** with a specific overload of function
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruit>` where you can specify which derived type it should deserialize to.

Try the below code:

```
namespace Console_SO
{
    public abstract class Fruit
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
    public class Apple : Fruit
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    class Orange : Fruit {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Apple
            var json = "{'$type': 'Console_SO.Apple, Console_SO','type':'Apple','color':'red'}";
            var fruit = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruit>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
            //Orange
             json = "{'$type': 'Console_SO.Orange, Console_SO','type':'Orange','color':'red'}";
             fruit = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruit>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
        }
    }

}
```

When sending the JSON to API you need to include a special `$type` property which holds the resolution details for the desired target derived type.
[TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).
Lastly, you should know that this approach is not perfectly safe and opens up code to some vulnerabilities. It may or may not be a concern depending on your environment. More details on this and workarounds [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2326?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `DeserializeObject`but unfortunately Fruit is not a parent class of Apple/Orange and we cannot make it so due to requirement. See the updated question for more information.