# Saving a model with an abstract class as a property into Raven

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, ravendb

Our project is a .NET Core Web API with a RavenDB backend and an angular 4 frontend.

In the Web API, I have a model as follows

```
public abstract class Offer
{
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class BasicOffer : Offer
{
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class StandardOffer : BasicOffer
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}


public class Section
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Offer> offers { get; set; }
}

public class Hub
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Section> sections { get; set; }
}
```

In our Angular app, we have the exact same models.

When try to update data using a POST request, the data sent by the Angular app contains the extra properties in the derived `BasicOffer` class, but when that data arrives at the Web API it only contains the properties in the base `Offer` class.

When I say "arrives", I mean putting a breakpoint on the first line of the POST request on the controller and looking at the parameters passed in.

Basically, how do I store data from a derived abstract class?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Abstract / Derived Class Deserialization with WebAPI 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408771/json-net-abstract-derived-class-deserialization-with-webapi-2)

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with RavenDB; this is a behavior issue with the Web API model serialization. The link above shows some workarounds.