# Binding and overriding a Model Type in ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Previous versions of ASP.Net exposed the inheritable class `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder`, which allowed the method `CreateModel` in order to return the **type** of model which the incoming request should bind to. It's very handy for having a single method for different base classes.

This doesn't exist in version 5. You can create Binders easily by inheriting from `IModelBinder` - in `BindModelAsync` the Model type can't be set. You *can* set the ModelMetadata.Model (which I believe would be an instantiation of the target type), but it's unclear how to set the Metadata itself which I think is needed.

Essentially I'm trying to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417888/mvc-3-model-binding-a-sub-type-abstract-class-or-interface) for the newer framework.

Answer (score 1):

The question turns out to be based on a misconception. The WebAPI stack has never had a DefaultModelBinder, that's the MVC stack. There's so much naming overlap that's it's confusing which is which; that's something ASP.Net 5.0 is trying to overcome.

The answer to this question - how to bind to a model different to the one specified in the method parameters - involves using the Json.NET library. A good overview of two different techniques can be [found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638741/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api).

This works perfectly well for ASP.Net 5.0 too.