# How to deserialize an abstract class that has many concrete implementations passed as an input to a C# ApiController method

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an APIController that one of its methods is expecting a `[FromBody] List<AbstractEntity>` . AbstractEntity is an abstract class and it is implemented by let's call them ConcreteEntity1 and ConcreteEntity2. How is this setup in C# .NET so that deserialization works? In my json everything is fine but an empty list of objects is passed in the APIController method.

Here is how the method looks:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("x/y/z")]
public void SomeMethod([FromBody] List<AbstractEntity> entities) { ... }
```

In Java Spring this is how I have set it in the past:
I have a variable nodeClass in each of the concrete implementations that is being checked against so the correct class is chosen during deserialization. In abstract entity I put those annotations at the top of the class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "nodeClass"
)

@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteEntity1.class, name="Concrete1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteEntity2.class, name="Concrete2"),
})
public abstract class AbstractEntity { ... }
```

I am hoping there is a concise solution that doesn't involve custom deserializers..

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using [tag:asp.net-web-api], correct?

Comment: @dbc I assume so - My controller extends System.Web.Http.ApiController and it is a pure json in/out controller without views

Comment: Does [Deserialising Json to derived types in Asp.Net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638741/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api) answer your question?  You could also check [JsonConverter with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321698), [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528648) or [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752) for alternative solutions.

Comment: @dbc All those are based on custom json deserializers right? I was expecting a simpler solution/configuration..

Comment: In the [Deserialising Json to derived types in Asp.Net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638741/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api) question, look at the second answer that uses `TypeNameHandling.Auto`

Comment: That's awesome @dbc. Thanks! That answer is kind of buried so I didn't see it the first time.